# How to use Spring DelegatingFilterProxy with multiple filters and Spring Security?

Tags: spring-mvc, filter, spring-security

We're using Spring security that's initialized using a `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`. We also have a separate web app initializer that extends from `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`. I've made the later as `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` as advised in the Javadoc of the former. So far so good.

Now I want to introduce additional Servlet filters that've nothing to do with Spring security and hence should be configured separately. I know that I can use a `DelegatingFilterProxy` to delegate requests to a Filter. But `DelegatingFilterProxy` doesn't have the capability to accept multiple filters.
One option is to define a custom `FilterChain` as done in Spring Security `FilterChainProxy`. That still creates 2 `DelegatingFilterProxy` and I understand that there should only be one `DelegatingFilterProxy` in the app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, this is how I did it:

I subclassed `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` and in it:

```
/**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] { requestContextFilter(), teFilterChain() };
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected FilterRegistration.Dynamic registerServletFilter(
            ServletContext servletContext, Filter filter) {
        String filterName = Conventions.getVariableName(filter);
        Dynamic registration = servletContext.addFilter(filterName, filter);
        if (registration == null) {
            int counter = -1;
            while (counter == -1 || registration == null) {
                counter++;
                registration = servletContext
                        .addFilter(filterName + "#" + counter, filter);
                Assert.isTrue(counter < 100, "Failed to register filter '"
                        + filter + "'."
                        + "Could the same Filter instance have been registered already?");
            }
        }
        registration.setAsyncSupported(isAsyncSupported());

        registration.addMappingForServletNames(getDispatcherTypes(), false,
                getServletName());
        return registration;
    }

    /**
     * Spring, by default, registers filters for 'FORWARD' dispatcher type as
     * well which causes TE filter chain to run again after Spring security
     * successfully authenticates and forwards the incoming request. We thus
     * exclude 'FORWARD' dispatcher type.
     */
    private EnumSet<DispatcherType> getDispatcherTypes() {
        return (isAsyncSupported()
                ? EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.INCLUDE,
                        DispatcherType.ASYNC)
                : EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.INCLUDE));
    }

    private Filter requestContextFilter() {
        return new DelegatingFilterProxy(TE_REQ_CTX_FILTER);
    }

    private Filter teFilterChain() {
        return new DelegatingFilterProxy(TE_FILTER_CHAIN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerDispatcherServlet(ServletContext ctx) {
        super.registerDispatcherServlet(ctx);

        registerSpringSecurityFilter(ctx);
        registerCorsFilter(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    protected DispatcherServlet createDispatcherServlet(
            WebApplicationContext servletAppContext) {
        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
        servlet.setThreadContextInheritable(true);
        servlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);

        return servlet;
    }

    private Dynamic registerCorsFilter(ServletContext ctx) {
        Dynamic registration = ctx.addFilter("CorsFilter", CorsFilter.class);

        registration.setInitParameter(CorsFilter.PARAM_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS,
                CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS);
        registration.setInitParameter(CorsFilter.PARAM_CORS_ALLOWED_METHODS,
                CORS_ALLOWED_METHODS);
        registration.setInitParameter(CorsFilter.PARAM_CORS_ALLOWED_HEADERS,
                CORS_ALLOWED_HEADERS);

        registration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(getDispatcherTypes(), false,
                "/*");

        return registration;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isAsyncSupported() {
        return true;
    }

    private final FilterRegistration.Dynamic registerSpringSecurityFilter(
            ServletContext servletContext) {
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addFilter(
                SPRING_SECURITY_FILTER_CHAIN, springSecurityFilterChain());

        if (registration == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Duplicate Filter registration for "
                    + SPRING_SECURITY_FILTER_CHAIN
                    + "'. Check to ensure the Filter is only configured once.");
        }

        registration.setAsyncSupported(isAsyncSupported());
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = getSecurityDispatcherTypes();
        /*
         * Don't use URL mapping for registering Spring security because then
         * the chain will kick in before DispatcherServlet.
         */
        registration.addMappingForServletNames(dispatcherTypes, true,
                getServletName());

        return registration;
    }

    private Filter springSecurityFilterChain() {
        return new DelegatingFilterProxy(SPRING_SECURITY_FILTER_CHAIN);
    }

    protected EnumSet<DispatcherType> getSecurityDispatcherTypes() {
        return EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ERROR,
                DispatcherType.ASYNC);
    }
```

Comment: Couldn't you use FilterChainProxy?

Comment: @lqbweb 3.5 years later, I don't remember.

Comment: @lqbweb 4 years later, FilterChainProxy part of security module, so what if the filter i am adding is not part of security and some other part?